# Meteor: what is "data context"?

Tags: meteor, datacontext

Just starting with Meteor, and going through the *[Meteor Tutorial](http://www.meteor-tutorial.org/)* by Matthew Platts.

In this tutorial, as well as in the official *[Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/)*, there are many references to the concept of **data context**, but I can't seem to find a cristal clear definition / explanation (with examples) of what this is.

For instance, in the [*2.4.3 Rendering Data with Helpers*](http://www.meteor-tutorial.org/book/1_1_first_app#uid40) section, we read:

> Notice that inside of the `#each` block we go `{{name}}`, even though
>   we have no name helper defined. This is because the **data context**
>   changes inside the `#each` block. We loop through each item in the
>   teams array, and since each item has a “name” attribute Meteor will
>   automatically create a `{{ name }}` helper.

**UPDATE**: Actually, just reading through the end of this very section, the author recommends a resource that makes things pretty clear: [*A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts*](http://www.meteor-tutorial.org/). Still no accurate definition though.

So, in Meteor, what is **data context** exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain as much as I know, correct me if I'm wrong.

I'll explain using following snippet:

```
<template name="posts">
  {{#each posts}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Let's assume it will display all the posts names from a blog:

```
First Post
Second post
Third post
..........
..........
```

I assume you know the concept of `helpers` and `events`.

In the above snippet, in general for `{{name}}`, meteor searches for the helper called `name` in helpers:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  name: function(){
   return "dummy text";
  }
});
```

If it finds any, it runs that helpers and displays the value.

So here, it outputs:

```
dummy text
dummy text
dummy text
...........
```

But if it doesn't find any helpers, it will search in `data context`.

Let's assume for posts we're returning some data:

```
   Template.posts.helpers({
      posts: function(){
       return Posts.find().fetch();
      }
    });
```

The data we're sending to `posts` helper looks like this:

```
{name: "First post", _id: "xxx", ......},
{name: "Second post", _id: "yyy", ......}
{name: "Third post", _id: "zzz", ......}
.................
```

In the code for `{{#each posts}}`, it loops through every object and displays `name property("First Post","Second Post,"Third Post")`.

It displays `name property` because it doesn't find any helper for `name`, and then it searches in the current `data context` and found property with the same name `name` and  displays that.

**Data context in helpers and events**

Let's take the same snippet and add a `delete` button:

```
<template name="posts">
      {{#each posts}}
        <p>{{name}}</p>
       <button>Delete Post</button>
      {{/each}}
    </template>
```

It displays like below:

```
First Post <Delete Post>
Second post <Delete Post>
Third post <Delete Post>
..........
..........
```

In the events:

```
Template.posts.events({
  'click button': function(){
     console.log(this)
    Posts.remove({_id: this._id });
  }
})
```

Here, when you click on any delete button, it will delete respective post.

Here we're using `this._id`: `this` means `data context`.

`this` will give you the data that the helper takes as input to display.

For example, if you click on the delete button beside `First Post`, then in the events it will give you following data as `this`:

```
{name: "First post", _id: "xxx", ......},
```

because that is the data context available when it displays that content.

Same if you click on the button beside `second post`:

```
{name: "Second post", _id: "yyy", ......},
```

And same goes with the `helpers` too.

I hope this helps at least someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to explain. Like you I used it in tutorial without knowing it. After some research I found the best explanation, **a visual one**. You can  have a look at [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) article about "Templates & Data Contexts". Hope it will clarify your mind about it.

Comment: Thanks. This is the article I am pointing to in the question update.

Answer (score 0):

A *data context* can be one of 3 things: (unless I've missed some)

1. A *cursor*, i.e. the result of a `Collection.find()`
2. An *array of objects*, i.e. just some array or the result of a `Collection.find().fetch()`
3. An individual object, i.e. `{ _id: "123", name: "Orthoclase E. Feldspar" }`

`{{#each foo}}` loops over a cursor or array context and changes the context to an individual object. `{{#with bar}}` just says which helper to use (in this case *bar*) to set the data context.

During development, but especially while learning Meteor, it helps to have `console.log(this)` at the top of your helper code just to double check what the data context is. It is *this*.